# Spark throws Exception when constructing Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I could construct the HbaseRdd from the Hbase table.After this,I am trying to convert it to a Scala case class DF.But getting Exception when converting from Bytes.toInt. Appricate the help from the experts

**Scala case class:**

```
case class UserProfile(User_Id: String, Card_Account_Number: Long, First_name: String, Last_name: String, email: String, gender: String, ip_address: String, user_name: String, address: String,phone:String,No_Transactions_in_24_hrs:Int,No_IPs_In_24_hrs:Int,TotalAmount_spent_in_24_hrs:Float,AvgAmount_spent_in_24_hrs:Float,Total_No_Transactions:Int,Amount_spent_so_far:Float)
```

// function to parse input

```
object UserProfile extends Serializable{
def parseUserProfile(result: Result): UserProfile = {

val p0=Bytes.toString(result.getValue(User_PersonalProfileBytes, Bytes.toBytes("User_Id")))

val p1 =Bytes.toLong(result.getValue(User_PersonalProfileBytes, Bytes.toBytes("Card_Account_Number")))

val p2=Bytes.toString(result.getValue(User_PersonalProfileBytes, Bytes.toBytes("First_name")))

val p3=Bytes.toString(result.getValue(User_PersonalProfileBytes, Bytes.toBytes("Last_name")))

val p4=Bytes.toString(result.getValue(User_PersonalProfileBytes, Bytes.toBytes("email")))
      val p5=Bytes.toString(result.getValue(User_PersonalProfileBytes, Bytes.toBytes("gender")))

val p6=Bytes.toString(result.getValue(User_PersonalProfileBytes, Bytes.toBytes("ip_address")))

val p7=Bytes.toString(result.getValue(User_PersonalProfileBytes, Bytes.toBytes("user_name")))

val p8=Bytes.toString(result.getValue(User_PersonalProfileBytes, Bytes.toBytes("address")))

val p9=Bytes.toString(result.getValue(User_PersonalProfileBytes, Bytes.toBytes("phone")))


val p10=Bytes.toInt(result.getValue(User_TransactionHistoryBytes, Bytes.toBytes("No_Transactions_in_24_hrs")))


val p11=Bytes.toInt(result.getValue(User_TransactionHistoryBytes, Bytes.toBytes("No_Ips_In_24_hrs")))

val p12=Bytes.toFloat(result.getValue(User_TransactionHistoryBytes, Bytes.toBytes("TotalAmount_spent_in_24_hrs")))

val p13=Bytes.toFloat(result.getValue(User_TransactionHistoryBytes, Bytes.toBytes("AvgAmount_spent_in_24_hrs")))

val p14=Bytes.toInt(result.getValue(User_TransactionHistoryBytes, Bytes.toBytes("Total_No_Transactions")))

val p15=Bytes.toFloat(result.getValue(User_TransactionHistoryBytes, Bytes.toBytes("Amount_spent_so_far")))


UserProfile(p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15)

    }}

**Spark-Hbase code :**

 val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val sparkConf1 = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    val tableName = "UserProfile"
    sparkConf1.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)
    sparkConf1.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2182");
    sparkConf1.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMNS,   
     "User_PersonalProfile","User_TransactionHistory");

    val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(sparkConf1,    classOf[TableInputFormat],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])

    println("Number of Records found : " + hBaseRDD.count())



     val count = hBaseRDD.count
      val resultRDD = hBaseRDD.map(tuple => tuple._2)
      println(resultRDD)
      val profileRdd=resultRDD.map(UserProfile.parseUserProfile)

      val userProfileDF = profileRdd.toDF()
       userProfileDF.printSchema()
       userProfileDF.show()

      userProfileDF.registerTempTable("UserProfileRow")
      sc.stop()
```

**Exception thrown:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toInt(Bytes.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toInt(Bytes.java:778)
    at com.research.spark.PaymentProcessor$UserProfile$.parseUserProfile(PaymentProcessor.scala:75)
    at com.research.spark.PaymentProcessor$$anonfun$5.apply(PaymentProcessor.scala:193)
    at com.research.spark.PaymentProcessor$$anonfun$5.apply(PaymentProcessor.scala:193)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:319)
    at com.research.spark.PaymentProcessor$.main(PaymentProcessor.scala:197)
    at com.research.spark.PaymentProcessor.main(PaymentProcessor.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toInt(Bytes.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toInt(Bytes.java:778)
    at com.research.spark.PaymentProcessor$UserProfile$.parseUserProfile(PaymentProcessor.scala:75)
    at com.research.spark.PaymentProcessor$$anonfun$5.apply(PaymentProcessor.scala:193)
    at com.research.spark.PaymentProcessor$$anonfun$5.apply(PaymentProcessor.scala:193)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: and what's the exception?...

Comment: @TzachZohar  :Updated the Exception Stack.Kindly have a look.

Comment: Looks like you have null values in one of the `Int` columns for some of the records - try checking for null before calling `Bytes.toInt`

Comment: I am reading a CSV file and created the table "UserProfile" with CFs User_PersonalProfile and User_TransactionHistory.The input file has no null values for any fields.Also I could see the HbaseRdd counts also.But when fetching I am getting Null values for all the fields including the String values.